# Delete Selected TreeNode from Xml C#

Tags: c#, xml, treeview

I am working on Winform using C#, i have populated Treeview from XML and need to Delete the treeview Selected Node ( Run time). Delete Event:

```
TreeNode node = treeView1.SelectedNode;
if (treeView1.SelectedNode != null)
{
    if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent == null)
        treeView1.SelectedNode.Remove();
    else if (treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Nodes.Count == 1)
        treeView1.SelectedNode.Parent.Remove();
    else
        treeView1.SelectedNode.Remove();
}

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("menu.xml");

var xElement = (from q in doc.Elements("root")
                where q.Attribute("quick").Value == node.Tag.ToString()
                select q);
foreach (var a in xElement) 
    a.Remove();
doc.Save("menu.xml");
```

Where my XML file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <quick title="1st Node" />
</root>
```

Comment: What is the problem with your current code?

Answer (score 1):

I understand that from the above xml you want to delete Node:quick. Try this:

```
doc.Root.Descendants("quick").FirstOrDefault().Remove();
```

This works if you have only one 'quick' node.

But there can be multiple 'quick' nodes, so to get the selected node to match in xml, u need to match the unique attribute value of that node to selected node same attribute value.

```
 doc.Root.Descendants("quick")
                           .First(x => x.Attribute("title").Value == node.Tag["title"].Tostring())
                           .Remove();
```